# What is the purpose of importing 'android.os.Bundle' in Android App Development?

Tags: android-bundle

What is the purpose of importing `android.os.bundle`in Android App Development?

Comment: SO and Google will help you !

Comment: Your question seems to ask about why we import `android.os.Bundle` class: It is imported to use the `Bundle` class ;) I think you want to ask what is the Bundle class!

Answer (score 0):

Bundle is a utility class that lets you store a set of name-value pairs. You will always find this import along with the import for Activity class because both onCreate() and onFreeze() methods take Bundle as a parameter. Into a Bundle object, you can put integers, longs, strings, arrays, etc along with the keys to identify them. When needed, these values can be obtained by using those keys.

So, as you can see, a bundle object is ideal for storing a set of state variables in the onFreeze method; and the same state variables can be read back in the onCreate method.

So, for example, in the snake game a series of state variables (direction, move delay, score, snake trail, etc) can be stored in a Bundle object (whether they are arrays, integers, strings, etc.).
http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/a-few-basic-imports-in-an-android-application-program.aspx